# Show a number of divs depending on a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How I can print N divs (each div represent a dot) dynamically? I am new in HTML and CSS, is there a way to print N divs depending on a variable. Do I need a Jquery function?

```css
.dot-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dot{
  width:10px !important; 
  height:10px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.red{
   background-color: red !important;
}
.blue{
   background-color: blue !important;
}
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="dot-container">
  <div class="dot red"></div>
  <div class="dot blue"></div>
  <div class="dot yellow"></div>
  <div class="dot red"></div>
</div>
```

Thats my code: https://jsfiddle.net/bpc8shra/

Comment: Do you want to duplicate the divs?

Comment: If so use [`$.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: what should be the final result? Do you want to add other dots side by side?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Well not clone, My question is about if there is a way to print 2 times this <div class="dot red"></div>, or 5 times, or 20 times...depending on the value of an integer variable.  If that variable is 7 so I have to be able to print 7 circles

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan yeah side by side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly, YOU mean something like this:

```
var red_dots = 15
for (var i=0; i<red_dots;i++)
  $('.dot-container').append('<div class="dot red"></div>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9sh7bm21/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with JS. Enter a number and click create button:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button")
, number = document.getElementById("number")
, ctn = document.getElementById("dot-container")
// Just a function to add random colors
, getRandomColor = function() {
  var hex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
  return "#" + ("000000" + hex.toString(16)).substr(-6);
}

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < Number(number.value); i++){
      let dot = document.createElement("div");
      dot.classList.add("dot")
      dot.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
      ctn.appendChild(dot)
  }
})
```

```css
.dot {
  width: 10px !important;
  height: 10px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number" />
<button id="button">Create</button><br/><br/>
<div id="dot-container">
</div>
```